# Home folder unintentionally exposed while using samba shares

Tags: kde, samba, file-sharing, smb

**Problem**

I have some difficulties with sharing folders in a **local area network** by using **samba**. I have managed everything up to the point that every folder that I share is being detected, can be read and can be written to. My problem however is, that next to the folders that I have explicitly shared, also my `/home/carlos` folder can be accessed. So basically **all my data is exposed unintentionally**. Currently I have my firewall blocking samba, so nothing is exposed at the moment, however I want to use samba though. I would like some assistance in correctly configuring samba.

**What have I done so far**

Copied default configuration file:

```
cp /etc/samba/smb.conf.default /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Changed workgroup from MYGROUP into Baptista and add these lines to the `[global]` section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
usershare allow guests = Yes
usershare max shares = 100
usershare owner only = False
```

Changed `[homes]` section configuration to read

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = No
    writable = No
```

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
# mkdir /var/lib/samba/usershares
# chgrp users /var/lib/samba/usershares/
# chmod 1775 /var/lib/samba/usershares/
# chmod +t /var/lib/samba/usershares/
```

(these commands and several settings were taken from section 1.7 of  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba/Troubleshooting)

Share a folder by launching Dolphin, right-click a folder, select properties, select the share tab, configure settings and press OK.

**Question**

Let assume I shared the folder `/home/carlos/Music`, then not only is `/home/carlos/Music` available through samba, my entire `/home/carlos` is available. How can I fix this, such that **only** the folders than I **explicitly** share, are shared?

**System information**

- Chakra Linux, 64-bit
- Linux kernel 3.12.6-1
- KDE 4.12.0
- Qt 4.8.5
- Samba 4.1.1-1
- Two laptops, same OS, same username

Comment: Are you sure that `[home]` section isn't actually `[homes]` (plural)?

Comment: Yes you are right it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

Your home directory is not being exposed. The `[homes]` section is a special section within the samba config. Basically it makes the home directory of the user you are logging in as accessible. So if you connect to samba as `cfbapista`, then it will make the home directory of `cfbapista` accessible. If the user `johndoe` connects, they will only see the home directory for `johndoe`, and not `cfbapista`.

You can find more details about the section in the [smb.conf man page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#HOMESECT).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by commenting out `[homes]` and all its fields.